# Problem in converting eps file to pdf

Tags: epstopdf

For converting `.eps` figures to `.pdf` I use package `epstopdf`. But in the converted figure is not exact as it is in `.eps` format. Can someone help me to resolve the problem?

Comment: Can you show an example? Without this, there isn't much information for anyone to work with.

Comment: Maybe it better, to convert it using ImageMagick-Tools or IrfanView or some similar tool?  There you have control about what and how ... Just store the resulting image with the same file name but different file extension.  Than you will be able, to say `\includegraphcis{myfile}` and LaTeX will append `.eps` while pdfLaTeX will search for `.pdf`.

Comment: @all-super-fast-closers: This post does not run away. You can still close it in 24 hours if there is still no update from the OP. Closing a post within an hour is a very unfriendly act and particularly inappropriate with newcomers. Most newcomers (like me some months ago) don't expect that this is a lively forum where they get immediate response. So they go away and come back only a few hours later. *So please stop hitting the close button.*

Comment: @gernot I wish I could give a bounty for a comment. :-)

Comment: @Jan: ImageMagick will convert even nice vector image EPS into bitmap PDF. So it should be used only for bitmap EPS.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: you are right.  In that case, you could use other converters as ADOBE InDesign or similar.  The ones I mentioned have the advantage, to be free of charge.